# Is it bad to learn multiple programming languages?

Tags: php, programming-languages, perl

I started learning PHP and I was able to get myself familiar with it. Now, I want to explore other programming languages like PERL so that I can compare it myself to PHP. Will I be confused to learn two language? Or are there any disadvantages?

Comment: look at this post as well - http://stackoverflow.com/q/682636/1437962

Comment: How many times do we have to answer this exact question?

Comment: PHP should take you to the end of your career! *no really it should, especially if this is a serious question!*

Comment: oh yeah, if you read the FAQ you would know this is way off topic as well. ["what language you should learn next, including which technology is better"](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/faq#questions)

Comment: Groan. PHP is the natural descendent of Perl. If studying Perl causes confusion??? Anyway, back in the day PHP just made pages pretty and was referred to as scripting which no Programmer would consider useful on a job reference. Funny how that's changed, we now use it to create applications.

Comment: @GregHewgill What happened to that "3-2-1 Contact" maxim "Just try it!" We'll be asked as long as people fail to realize another maxim, "Nothing ventured, nothing gained."

Comment: @FiascoLabs you can build houses out of toothpicks and duct tape, doesn't quantify the quality of the houses or the *applications*. *historial note: PHP originally mean Personal Home Page, they renamed it because of the negative connotations which are still valid, renaming it was a marketing gimmick, it didn't make it any better, just a way to avoid the negativity to the new generation of wanna-be-web-programmers that think HTML is code. Kind of like renaming the [Exxon Valdez](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exxon_Valdez) doesn't change the history behind the vessel.*

Comment: @FiascoLabs *"PHP is the natural descendent of Perl."* you just **offended every real Perl programmer in history the present and the future at one time!**

Comment: @Greg yet you still want to comment about it.

Comment: @JarrodRoberson And so you know, I was offended by it as well. I'm in total agreement with your assessment. To word it better? Derivative of? Unholy demon spawn of? Annoying script language that borrowed heavily from? Umm, all meant in fun. Oops now that's really off topic.

Comment: @FiascoLabs I think the Perl people would also offended by me saying *I think PHP makes Perl look reasonable!*, hell the die hards don't even consider `Perl 6` a natural descendent of Perl. :-) Plus they are usually a sensitive defensive bunch anyway, can't blame them trying to work with such a *write only* language. :-)

Answer (score 6):

I would spend some time getting decent at your first language, but once you have done that start exploring. There are a lot of languages out there and a lot of them are nicer then PHP or do something better.

I would take a look at the book "Seven Languages in Seven Weeks" which will walk you threw Ruby, IO, Scala, Prolog, Erlang, Clojure and Haskell which will make you  learn a whole bunch of new ways to code.

Comment: I think that's a good approach. Particularly importantly, it teaches you *different* languages. Learning Perl after PHP is not going to give you nearly as much insight as learning Prolog or Haskell!

Comment: qualify *getting decent* at PHP please? Because *getting decent* at PHP is way different that *getting decent* at say C++, Erlang or ASM.

Comment: good enough to get stuff done I guess. in truth my default rule for PHP is avoid if at all possible. One of my least favorite languages

Comment: +1 ZacharyK for recommending those languages. Infact, @mattmight in his post [What Every Computer Science Major Should Know](http://matt.might.net/articles/what-cs-majors-should-know/), recommended learning Racket, C, JavaScript, Squeak, Java, Standard ML, Prolog, Scala, Haskell, C++ and Assembly because they provide "a reasonable mixture of paradigms and practical applications". Put another way, the [Programmer's Competency Matrix](http://www.indiangeek.net/wp-content/uploads/Programmer%20competency%20matrix.htm) recommended Imperative, OO, declarative, functional, concurrent and Logic

Answer (score 5):

**Short Answer:** If you’re just starting your programming career, then I would advise you to focus on learning **just one programming language at a time**.

This is because there’s little to be gained by listing many programming languages on your resume **without really being good or highly skilled in any of them**!

**As a general rule,** it’s far better to learn one programming language and master it well before learning other programming languages.

Comment: I strongly disagree.  Unless by "master" you mean just learn the basics of loops, conditionals, case switches, functional programming, et. al. using your first language, before moving on to other languages.  I'd say once you have those basics quite well, you should study multiple languages in a short span of time and independently study up on as much *computer science* as you can.

Comment: I also disagree. Learning some new (even academic) language often improves your skill and programming style in other languages. So learning Scheme with [SICP](http://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) will improve your daily coding in PHP, Java, C or C++

Answer (score 3):

Learn anything that interests you.  If you want to learn Perl instead of studying PHP go ahead.  The most important thing is to be learning something.  In my opinion, knowing multiple languages at some level makes a better programmer than knowing only one in depth.

Answer (score 0):

I too started out with PHP. It's a good first choice as there is a pretty large community, and there is a good chance you can pick up a job writing it.

I wouldn't recommend picking up another similar language (such as PERL, Python, etc), as ultimately, you won't probably learn much other than more syntax. However, you might take some time and brush up on your javascript. jQuery is great, but that choice is yours. The best part? You can use both at the same time, so you can continue to grow professionally in both directions.